# How to write the following in LINQ syntax?

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Just wondering how to write the following SQL in LINQ syntax

```
select * from COESDetails
where COESNo in
(select distinct COESNo from COESDefects)
```

either Fluent or Query Expression, or Both

`COESDefects` have a navigation property to `COESDetails`

```
public class COESDefects
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int COESNo { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }       

    public virtual COESDetails COESDetails { get; set; }

}

public class COESDetails
{
    public COESDetails()
    {           
        COESDetailsCOESDefects = new List<COESDefects>();         
    }

    public int COESNo { get; set; }
    public int Postcode { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<COESDefects> COESDetailsCOESDefects { get; set; }            
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any navigation properties on COESDetails or COESDefects, or foreign key relationships of some sort? Are you using Entity Framework with a DBContext? Any additional information at all? These would be helpful to give you an answer that is not low quality.

Comment: updated question with navigation properties - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like it would be as simple as this:

```
yourDbContext.COESDetails.Where(detail => detail.COESDetailsCOESDefects.Any()).ToList();
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: awesome... just one modification yourDbContext.COESDetails.Where(detail => detail.COESDetailsCOESDefects.Any()).ToList();

Comment: Oops, obvious mistake. I write those all day, dunno how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query =
    from x in context.COESDetails
    join y in context.COESDefects on x.COESNo equals y.COESNo into ys
    where ys.Any()
    select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if the query is complex, it's easier to just execute it directly e.g.

```
IEnumerable<COESDetails> myResults = dbConext.ExecuteQuery<CCOESDetails>("select * from COESDetails where COESNo in (select distinct COESNo from COESDefects)")
```